# how to add json serilize data into the database using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my array and i want to convert this as json and added to the database

```
Array(

[0] => Array

    (

        [id] => e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5

        [channel] => Array
            (

                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )

    )
)
```

I want to store data like this where id remain same and channel will add to the next json bracket with same id

```
[{"id":"e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5","channel":1},{"id":"e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5","channel":2}]
```

**Code**

```
    $var1 = array([
                        'id' => $hash_user,
                        'channel' => $channel
                    ]);
                //  print_r($var1);
                    
                    foreach($var1 as $id){
                    
                        
                        $encode_data = $id['id'] . $id['channel'][0].  $id['id'] .  $id['channel'][1];
                        
                        $see = json_encode($encode_data);
                
                    
                    }
                    
                    print_r($see);
                    
                    print_r($encode_data);
                    //
                    die;
                    $info['user_hash'] = $encode_data;
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What code do you currently have? Delimited data is usually a bad choice for storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be clear in your post. But given the information, I assume you need to change the array you have to that JSON.

What you have:

```
$databaseArray = [[ "id" => "e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5", "channel" => [1,2]]];
$json = json_encode($databaseArray);
```

What you want:

```
$databaseArray = [[ "id" => "e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5", "channel" => 1]];
$json = json_encode($databaseArray);
```

What you need to change:

```
$databaseArray = [
    [ "id" => "e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5", "channel" => [1,2]],
    [ "id" => "1235437fbbce2345d7772b0674a32342", "channel" => [1,2]]
];
$databaseMergedArray = [];
     // You need to set the channel to a value instead of array. 
     foreach($databaseArray as $key => $item) {
         foreach($databaseArray[$key]["channel"] as $channel) {
             $item["channel"] = $channel;
             $databaseMergedArray[] = $item;
         }
     }

$json = json_encode($databaseMergedArray);
echo ($json);
```

Comment: thanks but i want the json result like this [{"id":"e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5","channel":1},{"id":"e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5","channel":2}]

Comment: i have multiple channel so i want each channel in individual json bracket

Comment: I've edited the post, this way will set the channels as an individual item